# Changing/punning types

Tags: c++, types, type-punning

I have a general question for situations where you need to change the type of a variable.

Let's say I have a float variable a but want it as an int, what I always did is

```
float a = 0.5;
int RoundedA = int(a);
```

However now I learned you should actually do it like:

```
float a = 0.5;
int RoundedA = (int)a;
```

The result of both is the same, so is it just a different style and it does the same, or is actually something different happening? And if so is there any performance difference between those two?

Comment: BTW your casts truncate, they don't round.

Comment: For the OC++D, you should do it like `int RoundedA = static_cast<int>(a);`